# Selecting historical records based on dates in a particular week

Tags: sql, oracle, date

I need to select all customers that have birthday in a week interval,it's kind of trigger that select every week the customers with birthdays on that week. So here is what I did(I work in pl/sql):

```
select customers_id 
  from customer_table 
 where to_char(cust_birth_dt,'DDD') between to_char(sysdate,'DDD') 
                                        and to_char(sysdate,'DDD') + 7;
```

It works good, but when it select the customer from a leap year, I get in trouble because of the number of days.

Anyone has an idea that could help me?

Comment: Do you *know* that this is not working for leap years?  It seems to be adding 7 days to the current day, which I believe should properly handle leap years.

Comment: an example:when i select the customers  only from today,wich is the 85 day of the year,i get for the years(2012,2008,2004,etc) the customers that have birthdays yesterday    It is working but not giving me the result i need

Comment: Why are you converting the dates into chars before adding the 7 seven days? What is the type of those fields?

Comment: Between date and date + 7 is a range of 8 days -- e.g.. Sunday-to-sunday.

Answer (score 0):

Did you notice that the years that are giving you trouble are leap years? The problem is that the day number on and after 1 March of any non-leap year is going to be one less than the day number of the same date in a leap year.

One way to calculate the same day across years is to hash each day of the year into a value such that the same day of every year, leap and non-leap, will have the same value and the hash of 29 Feb will be between 28 Feb and 1 Mar and will not collide with any other hash. The simplest way of doing that is to multiply the month by a value >= 31 (the number of days in the largest month) and add the day of the month. Any value >= 31 will do -- even a nice round number like 100. It ain't pretty and it ain't sargable:

```
Select  Customer_Id, cust_birth_dt
From    Customers
Where   (Extract( Month From cust_birth_dt * 100 +  Extract( Day From cust_birth_dt )
            >= Extract( Month From SysDate ) * 100 + Extract( Day From Sysdate ))
    and  (Extract( Month From cust_birth_dt * 100 +  Extract( Day From cust_birth_dt )
            < Extract( Month From SysDate + 7 ) * 100 + Extract( Day From SysDate + 7 ));
```

Using 100 allows us to quickly calculate the hash with just a glance at the date: 2/15/yyyy = 215, 10/25/yyy = 1025.

Now to make it prettier. Modeling to the rescue. As this search for birthdays seems to be something that is performed once a week, create a new table rather than add new columns to the existing table.

```
create table Birthday_info(
    Cust_ID  int not null,
    B_Date   date not null,
    B_Hash   int not null,
    constraint PK_Birthday_info primary key( Cust_ID ),
    constraint FK_Birthday_Customer foreign key( Cust_ID )
        references Customers( customers_id )
);
```

A simple query can populate it initially:

```
insert into Birthday_info
select customers_id, cust_birth_dt,
       Extract( Month From cust_birth_dt ) * 100 + Extract( Day From cust_birth_dt )
from   Customers;
```

To insure good performance:

```
create index IX_Birthday_Hash_ID on Birthday_info( B_Hash );
```

An "after insert, update, delete" trigger on the Customers table can keep the new table up to date.

Then your query would be:

```
Select  Cust_Id, Birth_Dt
From    Birthday_Info
Where   B_Hash >= Extract( Month From Sysdate ) * 100 + Extract( Day From SysDate )
    And B_Hash < Extract( Month From Sysdate + 7 ) * 100 + Extract( Day From SysDate + 7 );
```

Now it's sargable but still not very pretty. However, you can create a hashing function:

```
Select  Cust_Id, Birth_Dt
From    Birthday_Info
Where   B_Hash >= Hash_pkg.Date_Hash( SysDate )
    And B_Hash < Hash_pkg.Date_Hash( SysDate + 7 );
```

Much better.

Comment: Thank you guys for helping me,i solved the problem. First off all,please sorry my english. My problem was on the leap years after 29 february, because the day number of the current year was different from the day number of leap years

Comment: Well, don't keep us in suspense -- how did you solve the problem?

Comment: Well i tried both ways,the results are the same! Your method(TommCatt) is faster then the method that David Aldridge told me, so thank you again guys for helping me with this

Answer (score 0):

Representing the dates without the year portion, in a manner that preserves sorting, ought to do the trick:

```
select customers_id 
from   customer_table 
where  to_number(to_char(cust_birth_dt,'MMDD')) between
         to_number(to_char(sysdate    ,'MMDD')) and
         to_number(to_char(sysdate + 6,'MMDD'))
```

Strictly speaking the to_char is optional, but if you are going to try adding a function-based index on:

```
(to_number(to_char(cust_birth_dt,'MMDD','MMDD')))
```

... then it will keep that a little smaller.